# Will Stack Overflow for Teams be available WITHIN Stack Overflow Enterprise?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, stack-overflow-enterprise

I work for an organization that has an installation of SO Enterprise.  My team can't use it because of internal policies that restrict sharing info across teams.  We also can't use SO for Teams because we can't use external cloud apps.

But, I *think* we could use Enterprise if we could lock down our questions to only our team.  Is this going to be possible on an installation of Enterprise now that SO for Teams is released?

Comment: Looking at the [enterprise page](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise), it says that enterprise has unlimited teams.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes! "Teams" is now a core feature of the Stack Overflow software and will be available as part of [Stack Overflow Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise) starting with the next release.